# Variational principle perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory

I am trying to learn 2D SHO and free particle variational principles. However, I came across a perturbation like so: $Ax^2y^2$. The particle is simple harmonic in $x$ and a free particle in $y$? I'm not sure of how to calculate the variation to be added to the ground state.